# Promise.all inside loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ionic-framework, ecmascript-6, promise

Its an IONIC 2 app.

I am using Promise.all. I want to call a then function when all promises complete. Currently Then or catch is not getting called.

I dont know why I am not getting console.log(me.contactlist1);

Below is my code.

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef, nav: NavController) {
    console.log("FriendsPage::constructor");
    var client = window.skypeWebApp;
    let me = this;
    client.personsAndGroupsManager.all.groups.subscribe();
    client.personsAndGroupsManager.all.groups.get().then(function (groups) {
    let tagGroup = [];
    for(let group in groups)
    {
        if (groups[group].name())
            tagGroup.push(me.createGroupView(groups[group]));
      }
      console.log(tagGroup);

      Promise.all(tagGroup).then((results) => {
            console.log(me.contactlist1);
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });

        console.log("hey");
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log("friendstest3");
    });
}

createGroupView(contactsObj)
{
    let me = this;
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let contacts = contactsObj.persons;
        contacts.subscribe();
        console.log("hello");
        let all;
        contacts.get().then(function(contact){
            console.log("friendstest1");
            console.log(contact);
            let temp = {key: contactsObj.name(), value: contact}
            all = temp;
            me.contactlist1(all);
            resolve(all);
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors thrown in the `createGroupView()` function? Your invoking `me.contactlist1()` as if it's a function, is this correct?

Comment: Ohhh.. I feel like an idiot! I wanted to push in an array. That was the exact error. Thanks!!